# Swagger UI Displaying a pop up window message on execute before processing

Tags: swagger-ui

I want to display a pop up window message with a <kbd>OK</kbd> and <kbd>Cancel</kbd> on execute before the processing happens. Clicking <kbd>OK</kbd> will continue processing. <kbd>Cancel</kbd> will cancel the execution.

How can I achieve this?

[image]

I have googled for a solution but haven't come across any. Is this even possible?

Comment: May I ask why you need this? Users typically want _less_ clicks, not more clicks.

Comment: @Helen, we have a requirement where we want to display a warning message (this will result in such and such, etc) to the user. We will not be showing this message every time. We'll only show this message depending on the content of the request body.